# tkinter root bg color

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on creating a schedule by using tkinter. I set the root bg color to white in my code, but it's not getting white. (I also set some labels to white to see whether it becomes white or not.)

However, it works when I test it in a new file.

This is my schedule code.

```
root=Tk()
root['bg']='white'
cp=coursePlan(root)
cp.pack()
root.title('Schedule')
root.mainloop()
```

This is my test code.

```
root=Tk()
root['bg']='white'
l=Label(root,text='test')
l.grid(row=0,column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: schedule code UI]

[image: test code UI]

Comment: What is `coursePlan`? If that's a Frame, then you need to set the background of that to white too: `cp=coursePlan(root, bg='white')`. Unused space in Tkinter objects is not transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign a `parent` to widgets like `Label(root, ...)` when the widget is displayed, by default the widget occupies some space *over* its parent.

The widgets have their own background colors which are not necessarily transparent, thus If a widget has its `bg` set to `'red'` while it's parent's `bg` is set to `'white'` there are basically three outcomes:

1. widget gets displayed with a fill option selected (`pack(fill=...` or `grid(sticky=...)`) or the widget overfits its parent in both x and y dimensions, which results in the parent being entirely behind the widget and thus only widget's bg, `'red'`, is displayed.
2. widget gets displayed with some or no regard to resizability and thus occupies its parent partially, in which case both the widget's and its parent's bg, `'red'` and `'white'`, is displayed
3. Finally, the widget isn't displayed at all, so only the parent's bg, `'white'`, is displayed.

See below demo:

```
import tkinter as tk


def demo(*args):
    if choice.get() == 1:
        widget.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    elif choice.get() == 2:
        widget.pack(fill='x', expand=False)
    elif choice.get() == 3:
        widget.pack_forget()

def default(event):
    root.state('zoomed')
    choice.set(2)
    widget.pack(fill='x', expand=False)

root = tk.Tk()

root['bg'] = 'white'
root.state('zoomed')

widget = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Displaying Options", bg='red')

choice = tk.IntVar(value=2)
fill = tk.Radiobutton(widget, variable=choice, text="Fill / Overfit", value=1)
no_resize = tk.Radiobutton(widget, variable=choice,
                            text="Some / No regard to resizability", value=2)
no_display = tk.Radiobutton(widget, variable=choice, text="Not displayed",
                                                                    value=3)
choice.trace_add('write', demo)     # to call demo when choice is modified
root.bind_all("<Escape>", default)  # to go back to initial state when user hits esc

widget.pack(fill='x', expand=False)
fill.pack(side='left')
no_resize.pack(side='left')
no_display.pack(side='left')
root.mainloop()
```